# How to match new lines as one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to turn this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
```

into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<p>Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
```

To accomplish that I split the paragraphs, applied a regex, and finally joined them again:

```
data = data.split('\n\n')
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = data[i].replace(/(.+)/g, '<p>$1</p>')
}
data = data.join("")
```

Unfortunately the output is this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><p>Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
<p>eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
```

Each line of the paragraph is being considered as a single paragraph.

How can I modify my code so I get the desired result?

Comment: regexes by default operate on a per-line basis. there's a `\n` after your `consetetur`, causing the `(.+)` to stop matching there. Try adding the multi-line flag: `/(.+)/gm`.

Comment: Use `data.join("\n\n")`

Comment: @Marc B Weird, I added the `m`. Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need the regexp? This should work too.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    data[i] = '<p>' + data[i]+ '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex you can do:

```
data = date.replace(/^(\S[\s\S]+?)(?=\n\n|$(?!\n))/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR1fE0/1)

Comment: Nice. Are there any benefits over using a `for` loop as I did? Or it's the same thing?

Comment: I believe this is lot less code and easier to understand. In terms of efficiency I think both approaches will be more or less same though.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [\s\S] to match any character include newline, so my modification:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = data[i].replace(/([\s\S]+)/g, '<p>$1</p>');
}
```

Comment: I don't want to include the newline.