# Why is this p tag being added as a new line?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The following code splits `data`, applies a regex, and joins the string again (there's a part that removes new lines between words because I want the paragraphs to be output in a single block/line):

Input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
>
> Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore

Code:

```
data = data.split('\n\n')
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = '<p>' + data[i].replace(/\n(?=\w+)/g, ' ') + '</p>'
}
data = data.join('\n\n')
```

I thought the input would be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<p>Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
```

But no, it's instead:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<p>Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
</p>
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Isn't this question this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124091/how-to-match-new-lines-as-one ?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ No, I'm asking a totally different thing.

Comment: And what's the problem, newlines in HTML shouldn't matter ?

Comment: Also, can not reproduce -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4o5w2oj6/**

Comment: You cannot create a multiline string in javascript

Comment: it is because you have a newline at the end of your real string (not the one in your post), so since it isn't followed by a word character, the newline is not replaced. You can change the lookahead like this: `(?=\w|$)`. As an aside, it is useless to add a quantifier here `(?=\w+)`, `(?=\w)` will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a trailing newline in your original string, but you can solve the problem with a little change. Instead of checking if there is a word character after a newline, check if there is no whitespace characters after:

```
var data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n"
         + "\n"
         + "Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur\n"
         + "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore\n";

var data = data.split('\n\n');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = '<p>' + data[i].replace(/\n(?!\s)/g, '') + '</p>'
}
data = data.join('\n\n');

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your output shows a newline before the closing `</p>` tag, then your *real world* input must contain a newline at the end. The following code works well for me:

```
/* note that you cannot declare a multiline string in javascript
   like you did. I'm using `Array.join()` to create the example data */
data = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "",
  "Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur",
  "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore"
].join("\n");

data = data.split('\n\n')
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = '<p>' + data[i].replace(/\n(?=\w+)/g, ' ') + '</p>'
}
data = data.join('\n\n')
```